# Updating a Tkinter Listbox from empty list

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm struggling again to figure out a way to update my tkinter listbox from a combobox selection.

What I want to happen is the user imports an excel file, the file is then read and all the sheets available on that workbook is displayed for the user to select (this part works - Combobox), once its selected it suppose to display all the headers in that excel sheet in a listbox so the user can select multiple headers. The headers changes depending on the sheet selected, so the listbox would have to update and display the new headers.

I figured out how to display it as a ComboBox and it'll update as different sheets are selected, but I need the ability to select multiple headers - hence why I'm trying to use a listbox.

I've pasted what I've got right now.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlrd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import tkinter as tk
import re
import numpy as np

class myApp:
    importedSheets = []
    headers = []
    reports = ['A','B','C','D']
    # rb_select = IntVar()

    def UploadAction(self):
        self.filename = askopenfilename()
    
    def SaveAction(self):
        self.savelocation = asksaveasfilename()

    def sheetnames(self):
        self.xlssheets = xlrd.open_workbook(self.filename,on_demand=True)
        importedSheets = self.xlssheets.sheet_names()
        self.cbox_sheets.config(value=importedSheets) #updating the value of the combobox
        return importedSheets
               
    def headernames(self):
        if self.reporttype.get(self.reporttype.curselection()) == self.reports[0]:
            self.df = pd.read_excel(self.filename,sheet_name = self.cbox_sheets.get(),header = 1, index_col=0)
            headers = list(self.df.columns)
            self.headerselectors.config(values=headers)
        
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.filename = None
        self.master = master
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
    # Creating Basic Frame Structure
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
        self.frame1 = Frame(master=master,relief=RAISED,borderwidth=1)
        self.frame1.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    
        self.frame2 = Frame(master=master,relief=RAISED,borderwidth=1)
        self.frame2.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    
        self.frame3 = Frame(master=master,relief=RAISED,borderwidth=1)
        self.frame3.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
    # Frame 2 - Selecting Sheet and Header To Work with
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
        self.frame2a = Frame(master = self.frame2)
        self.frame2b = Frame(master = self.frame2)
        self.frame2r = Frame(master = self.frame2)
        self.frame2a.pack(side=TOP)
        self.frame2b.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.frame2r.pack(side=RIGHT)
    
    
        self.uploadLabel = Label(master = self.frame2a,text = '1) Select the file you want to import',font=(None,12,)).pack()
    
        self.uploadButton = Button(master = self.frame2a,text = 'Import', command =lambda:self.UploadAction()).pack(padx=5,pady=5)
    
        self.reporttype = Listbox(master=self.frame2a,height=4,selectmode=SINGLE,exportselection = False)
        for x,reports in enumerate(self.reports):
            self.reporttype.insert(x,reports)
    
        self.reporttype.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
    # Selecting Sheets to work with:
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
        self.sheetLabel = Label(master = self.frame2b,text = '2) Select the sheet to extract',font=(None,12)).pack(padx=15)
    
        self.cbox_sheets = Combobox(master = self.frame2b,values = self.importedSheets,postcommand = self.sheetnames)
        self.cbox_sheets.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
    
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
    # Selecting Headers to Work with:
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------#
         self.headerLabel = Label(master = self.frame2r,text = '3) Select the header with data',font=(None,12)).pack(padx=15)
    
         self.headerselectors = Combobox(master = self.frame2r,values = self.headers,postcommand = self.headernames)
         self.headerselectors.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
    
                  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    my_gui = myApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: The section that needs to be worked on is in: Selecting Headers to Work with (I don't know how to highlight on stackoverflow)

Comment: Fix the indentation please and highlight part of code that is relevant to this issue.

Comment: @CoolCloud fixed indentation, I'm not sure how to highlight (couldn't figure that out too lol) - you actually helped me earlier with the sheet selection combobox.

Comment: You can see that the indentation is still not fixed right?

Comment: @CoolCloud I see it, the indentation between Class & Defs. Got it!

Comment: do you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not commnt) as text (not screeshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas no I don't get any error messages.

Comment: it is strange - you have list `importedSheets = []` but you use it as function in `return self.importedSheets()` - you should remove `()`. Did you run code in console/terminal to see error messages? And you can always use `print()` to see values in variables to see if code works as you expect.

Comment: I'm sorry - I should've removed that. I can comment that out or remove it, and the code still works as it should for sheet selecting

Comment: it would be much simpler if you put code with all imports - and then we could simply copy and run code.

Comment: @furas added the full code.

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT!!! I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0):

To create a dynamic listbox I had to bind it to a button:

```
    self.headerLabel = Label(master = self.frame2r,
                             text = '3) Select the header with data',
                             font=(None,12)).pack(padx=15)
        
    self.headers_button = Button(master = self.frame2r, text = 'Show Headers',command = self.headernames).pack()
    self.headers_select = Listbox (master = self.frame2r,exportselection = False,selectmode=MULTIPLE)
    self.headers_select.pack()
```

Once I created the basic listbox and button I added to my function `def headernames(self):`

```
    def headernames(self):
        if self.reporttype.get(self.reporttype.curselection()) == self.reports[0]:
            self.df = pd.read_excel(self.filename,sheet_name = self.cbox_sheets.get(),header = 1, index_col=0)
            headers = list(self.df.columns)
            self.headers_select.delete(0,'end')
            for x,header in enumerate(headers):
                self.headers_select.insert(x,header)
```

Now everytime I click on the button "Show Headers" it'll clear the list and then add the new headers for the selected sheet.